# one-liner (without VBA) to evaluate in what VLAN an IP Address would be

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(InVlan (calc)) needs to be evaluated, based on what "LowestIP" is the next smaller number from the "IPAddress"

```
VLAN    LowestIP
Vlan A  192.168.10.0
Vlan B  192.168.10.16
Vlan C  192.168.10.128
Vlan D  192.168.20.0
Vlan E  192.168.20.16
Vlan F  192.168.20.128
Vlan G  10.11.12.0
Vlan H  10.11.12.13
Vlan I  10.11.12.100
```

---

```
IPAddress   InVlan (Calc)   Expected
192.168.10.14   ?            Vlan A
192.168.10.15   ?            Vlan A
192.168.10.16   ?            Vlan B
192.168.10.17   ?            Vlan B
10.10.10.10     ?            N/A
10.11.12.11     ?            Vlan G
192.168.20.200  ?            Vlan F
192.168.20.10   ?            Vlan D
192.168.20.100  ?            Vlan E
192.168.10.13   ?            Vlan A
192.168.10.130  ?            Vlan C
10.11.12.14     ?            Vlan H
10.11.12.140    ?            Vlan I
```

Comment: How have you tried to solve this? This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. You can familiarize yourself with this site by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

To tackle your problem, I used the following helper table, which includes three helper columns to convert the **LowestIP** addresses into numerical values.

[image: Helper Table]

- **Helper 1** `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","")` It removes all single dot `.` from the IP address;
- **Helper 2** `{=3-(LEN(A2)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND(".",A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))),0)))}` It finds out if the fourth value in the IP address is either units (`returns 2`), tens (`returns 1`) or hundreds digit (`returns 0`). Please note it is an **array formula** so you need to press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to make it work.
- **Helper 3** `=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-3+D2)&REPT(0,D2)&RIGHT(C2,3-D2))` Using the value from Helper 1 and Helper 2, we can work out the equivalent numerical value of each IP address. Eg. 192.168.10.**1** will be converted to 19216810**001**.
- The last step is to **sort the last column (Helper 3) from smallest to largest**. It is a vital step otherwise the subsequent look up will not return the correct value.
- An optional step is to name Column B as **VLAN**, and name Column E as **Lookup**. It will make it easier when inputting the look up formula.

On the look-up sheet where you have all the IP addresses that you want to look up the VLAN names, **you also need to create the three helper columns** to obtain the numerical value of the IP addresses.

[image: Lookup Table]

Then you can add a column named **InVlan** at the end of the above table and in the first cell enter the following formula and drag it down.

```
=INDEX(VLAN,MATCH(J2,Lookup,1))
```

[image: Result]

Here I used **INDEX+MATCH** to look up the VLAN name from the helper table. When using MATCH you need to use `1 - less than` as the **[Match_Type]**.

You can use **VLOOKUP** instead but you need to move the VLAN column of the helper table to the end, and use `TRUE - Approximate match` as the **[Range_Lookup]**.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Can you please share the excel sheet to clarify the answer. Thanks

Comment: @ROHITMUNDHRA the relevant formulae are given, all you need to do it type them and adjust the ranges to suit your data. This is the accepted way on here, we do not post and exchange spreadsheets due to the possibility of viruses. While I might be running virus protection, I can't be sure you are...

Comment: @ROHITMUNDHRA feel free to ask me which part of my answer is unclear to you and I can clarify further if possible. If it is not working for you please provide me the instances. Glad to help :)